# double quotes are invalid in JSON validator even after manually replacing these text quotes in a code editor

Tags: json, validation

I was given a payload and was preparing it to be JSON. When validating, it says the double quotes are invalid. I tried opening the file in VS Code and deleted and retyped over the invalid text quotes with double quotes, saved the file and then validated again, but the JSON validator still says these double quote marks are invalid. Anyone else run into this problem? I really don't want to have to type the entire file manually from scratch.

This is an example of some of the code that's causing this error in the JSON validator:

```
{
    "conjunctive": "&&",
    "conditionKey": "nested condition",
    "operator": "nested condition",
    "conditionValue": "nested condition",
    "description": "nested condition"
}
```

I know this is a long shot....I am surprised this is happening, but, hoping anyone knows what to do here. I tried the JSON validator in Sublime and the two at these URLs 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Comment: I copied & pasted your JSON into both of the websites you provided, and both of them said that it's perfectly valid.

Comment: Yep, that is valid JSON you have there.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. It was making me crazy and once I started over with the original file that I was sent, the problem was not happening. But the first time, something weird was going on. This website is an online tool to replace smart quotes and this did the trick for me. https://dan.hersam.com/tools/smart-quotes.html